# Finite fields package doesn't simplify

Tags: evaluation, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

I'm trying to do arithmetic using the FiniteFields package. Supposing a is a generator of a Galois field (say GF(2^5)) I want to be able to simplify things like a^32 and (a^8)^-1. I don't care about the polynomial representation of a, though sometimes I might want to work with say GF(2^5)[x]. However the FiniteFields package doesn't do this; it just leaves things in

```
{PowerMod[1.{1, gf3, gf3^2, gf3^3, gf3^4}, -1, 32], 0, 0, 0, 0}_32
```

Any idea how I can get it to do this?

Thanks.